# Meteor - Exception in setInterval callback: ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Tags: jquery, meteor

I have a game in which if a user answers correctly btn-success is added or if incorrectly btn-danger is added. This happens on the client.

```
    'click .question': function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if(submission === correctAnswer) {
            $(e.target).closest('a').addClass("btn-success");
        } else {
            $(e.target).closest('a').addClass("btn-danger");
        }
    }
});
```

Once the clock hits zero, which is accomplished on the server, I want any classes such as btn-success or danger to be removed

```
Meteor.methods({
    windDown: function(gameId) {
        var interval = Meteor.setInterval(function () {

            // end of game
            if (clock <= 0 ) {
                // stop the clock
                Meteor.clearInterval(interval);
                //remove conditional formatting
                $('a').removeClass( "btn-success btn-danger" );
            }
        }, 1000);
    }
});
```

However, I get an error of:

```
Exception in setInterval callback: ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to use jQuery on server, but it only works on client side.

There is way to call client from server, check package : http://atmospherejs.com/anticoders/client-call

Comment: How would you suggest I go about accomplishing the behavior without Jquery on the server?

Comment: I would synchronize state of question and state of game via collection.
Show your model/collections so I can try to help you.